# add web service reference to eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, web-services, service

I'm building a android application and I need to consume a web service. I am using eclipse as my ide.

Does Eclipse have a nice easy way to add the web service to the project like the way visual studio does?

Is there a plugin?

I tried this http://wsdl2javawizard.sourceforge.net/  but I cant find "Import Web Reference" in my latest version of eclipse

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

World,

In android/java nothing  exist like add service or add webservice reference facility as you have in visual studio.

So, you need to first do analysis of following to proceed further:

1) Either you are using soap based webservice? or restful api?

A: If you are using soapbased service that is developed in dotnet then you need to use any free library to consume it like: (ksoap) i used 1 year ago.

B: similary if you are using restfull with json (then Gson is the Google library which is very easy and helpful.

I hope i have given you the direction now you can explore these yourself :)

Comment: thnaks very much for your reply is ksoap easy and are there example?

Comment: No its not that much easy for dotnet guys but atleast you will need some time to explore it first. becausee in java debugging is tough as compared to donet here is sample tutorial: http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html.